# Express JS: Send Databse as Variable / Parameter while requiring a module

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Say I have the following code

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./permissions.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://blah-blah-blah.firebaseio.com"
});
const db = admin.firestore();
app.use("/auth", require("./auth"));
```

Now the problem is that I have to use the cloud firestore databse functionality, which is curently stored in the variable db, in my auth.js file as well, without using admin.initializeApp a second time. Is there any way to acomplish that, like importing/exporting the db variable etc.

This is where I am using it in auth.js:

```
 const express = require("express");
  const auth = express.Router();
  db.collection("data")
      .doc("sample")
      .get()
      .then(
        document => {
          if (document.exists) {
            return done(null, {
              id: user.id,
              name: user.name,
              email: user.email
            });
          } else {
            //create document
          }
        },
        err => {
          //handle error
        }
      );
```

Of course, right now db will be undefined, which is the problem I need to tackle

Comment: Needs more explanation as to what is required.

Comment: What else do you think is unclear?

Comment: What exactly are you doing with `app.use("/auth", require("./auth"));`?

Comment: Since version 1.0.0 of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions you have to initialize with `admin.initializeApp();`. Then, to interact with Firestore, you just need to use the Admin SDK, for example as follows: `admin.firestore().collection('....').get();`.

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec checking if some specific documents exists in a collection

Comment: Can you share more details on the `auth` code?

Comment: You can probably just use `require('firebase-admin').firestore()` elsewhere in your app after `admin.initializeApp` has been used.

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec I have already used admin.initialiizeApp once in index.js, and as i mentioned in the question I want to know if I could acomplish this without using admin.initializeApp again in auth.js

Comment: If you don't share your entire code (all modules) it will be difficult for us to help you.

Comment: just edited the question to include the part where I'm using it

Comment: The files contain lots of code, and I've just included the code concerning my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 1.0.0 of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions you have to initialize with `admin.initializeApp();`, see the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#new_initialization_syntax_for_firebase-admin).

Then, to interact with Firestore, you just need to use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore), for example as follows:

```
admin.firestore().collection('....').get();
```

So, if I understand correctly your question, the following changes should do the trick:

**index.js**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

//const db = admin.firestore();   not sure you need that here, it depends if you interact (or not) with Firestore in index.js

app.use("/auth", require("./auth"));
```

**auth.js**

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const db = admin.firestore();
//....
db.collection("data")
      .doc("sample")
      .get()
      .then(
        document => {
          if (document.exists) {
            return done(null, {
              id: user.id,
              name: user.name,
              email: user.email
            });
          } else {
            //create document
          }
        },
        err => {
          //handle error
        }
      );
//....
```